# vertical alignment - can't put display table on parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Common question - vertically centring a div, but I can't put 'display: table' on the parent div.

HTML hierarchy ( Bootstrap 3 layout used - I removed php content to make it simpler, all divs are needed)

```
<article>

   <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

      <div class="row">

         <div class="col-md-8 indx-img " style="background-image:url('...');">
         </div>

         <div class="col-md-4">

           <div class="text-cell">
             <h1>title</h1>
             <h3>category</h3>
           </div>

        </div>

      </div><!-- /#row -->

   </div><!-- /#post -->

</article>
```

CSS

```
article {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

.indx-img {
  position: relative;
  padding: 16% 0;
}
```

I want 'text-cell' to be vertically aligned in col-md-4. I can't put display:table on 'article' because it screws up the column layout. There are no known heights, the article height is based off of padding:16% 0; of the indx-img class

Comment: Can you make a `jsfiddle` to find a solution

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hunt0194/uq799zfa/2/  Can't seem to bring in the bootstrap frame-work externally

Comment: I upadate your jsfiddle with bootstrap...question: col-md-4 is not the same height as col-md-8. - https://jsfiddle.net/uq799zfa/3/  I put margin and padding  zero on the <h1> and <h3>. My question is - vertical center based on col-md-4 or col-md-8 . Right now text-cell use all height of the col-me-4

Comment: I need both heights the same (col-md-4 and col-md-8 should be the same height) I'm not sure how to do that. I want text-cell to be centred to col-md-8

Comment: i noticed the columns in your fiddle (and mine) are not beside each other (Bootstrap has the column's take up the full width and are adjacent to each other, col-md-4 on the left, col-md-8 on the right